# Convert Jira markup to HTML

Tags: html, jira, pandoc

I am creating a dynamic report in jsreport cloud application and I have JSON with extracted data from JIRA Xray REST API which then maps into the report. The thing is that the field texts (JSON values) are coming in Jira markup language and I’m writing the report in HTML. Therefore everything maps together with JIRA markup tags.

Does anybody know how to convert markup to HTML automatically?

I know about Pandoc, but converting text manually and pasting it into a report is not an option. How to integrate this stuff into jsreport I have no idea. I saw there is an API and library but it is in Haskell language.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you know about pandoc, and probably about its ability to convert JIRA wiki markup to HTML via `pandoc --from=jira --to=html`. So all you could just call out to pandoc for all strings. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: maybe you want to use https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-server

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, you're accessing the /rest/api/3/issue/issueIdOrKey REST API endpoint and hoping to retrieve the issue description in HTML.

All you have to do is to append the argument to expand the rendered fields to your REST API call, like in below example:

[https://NAME.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{ISSUE-KEY_OR_ID}?expand=renderedFields](https://NAME.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/%7BISSUE-KEY_OR_ID%7D?expand=renderedFields)

This will return response in hTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a VS Code extension called `JiraLens`, where I also need to handle this conversion from Jira markdown to HTML.

Here is my approach in Typescript:

```
import { DOMSerializer } from 'prosemirror-model';
import { defaultSchema } from '@atlaskit/adf-schema/schema-default';
import { WikiMarkupTransformer } from '@atlaskit/editor-wikimarkup-transformer';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const transformer = new WikiMarkupTransformer();
const pmNode = transformer.parse(markdown);
const dom = new JSDOM();
const document = dom.window.document;
const target = document.createElement('div');
const html = DOMSerializer.fromSchema(defaultSchema).serializeFragment(
  pmNode.content,
  { document },
  target
) as HTMLElement;
return html.outerHTML;
```

Note that certain markdowns are not handled properly (e.g. coloured text). I also tried to develop a conversion logic but it wasn't good enough for complex cases. If anyone found a perfect solution I would love to hear about that.

Besides, if you want to go further and convert Jira markdown to normal markdown:

```
import TurndownService from 'turndown';

const html = convertJiraMarkdownToHtml(markdown);
const turndownService = new TurndownService();
turndownService.addRule('strikethrough', {
  filter: ['del', 's'],
  replacement: (content) => '~' + content + '~'
});
return turndownService.turndown(html);
```